# Can I combine values of two rows with slightly different labels in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes that I want to combine. However, the name of the rows are slightly different from each other. Is it possible to combine them using pandas?

```
**df1**
Date        Campaign     Units sold  Sales 
11/07/2020  AMZ ABCDEFG  1           $10
12/07/2020  AMZ ABCDEFG  2           $20
13/07/2020  AMZ ABCDEFG  3           $30

**df2**
Date        Campaign     Clicks    Spend
11/07/2020  GA ABCDEFG   10        $5
12/07/2020  GA ABCDEFG   15        $6
13/07/2020  GA ABCDEFG   20        $7

**Desired output**
Date       Campaign  Clicks  Units sold   Spend   Sales
11/07/2020 ABCDEFG   10      1            $5      $10
12/07/2020 ABCDEFG   15      2            $6      $20
13/07/2020 ABCDEFG   20      3            $7      $30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to clean the output a bit, but this looks like what you need.

```
df1["Campaign_id"] = df1["Campaign"].str.split(expand=True)[1]
df2["Campaign_id"] = df2["Campaign"].str.split(expand=True)[1]
df = df1.merge(df2, on=["Campaign_id", "Date"], how="outer")
print(df)

         Date   Campaign_x  Units sold Sales Campaign_id  Campaign_y  Clicks  \
0  11/07/2020  AMZ ABCDEFG           1   $10     ABCDEFG  GA ABCDEFG      10   
1  12/07/2020  AMZ ABCDEFG           2   $20     ABCDEFG  GA ABCDEFG      15   
2  13/07/2020  AMZ ABCDEFG           3   $30     ABCDEFG  GA ABCDEFG      20   

  Spend  
0    $5  
1    $6  
2    $7
```

Comment: I used this and got an error that said "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 13, placement implies 1". Can you help me understand the issue and help me resolve it as well? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To have the expected output :

`df3 = df1.merge(df2[['Date','Clicks','Spend']],on = 'Date')`

Then standardize `Campaign` :

`df3["Campaign"].str.split(expand=True)[1]`